# SSRS 2005 - Email Subscriptions sending out old report version

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a problem with Sql Server 2005 Reporting Server where people are receiving old versions of a report whenever the report is sent through a subscription.

I've added a date to the footer of the report, build and deployed it but subscribers still receive an older report.

I am not able to find any known issue or someone with a similar problem and could use some guidance on what to do.

Comment: Bit of a guessing game without more information. Some things that come to mind: What does the report look like if you view it through the web interface"? Have you tried adding your own mail address to the subscription? Perhaps also delete and re-create the subscription on the newly uploaded report? Or delete the report via the web interface and see if it's still mailed out at all?

Comment: Delete the existing subscription and create new it will definetly help you. Don't forget to double check on the report name.

Comment: @Jeroen The report looks fine when run manually. Subscribed myself and received an older version of the report.

Comment: @PratikGupta THank you. What do you mean by "check on the report name"

Comment: Hmm, weird. Try deleting the report in the web interface, re-deploying it (perhaps with a new name?), and re-creating the subscription, then see what happens?

Comment: @IEnumerator Its just(silly mistake i did) the report name for which the subscritions are going is the same which you are deploying and also check the overwrite for report to true.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Properties` -> `Execution`. There are options there to have the report run based on a cached copy or from a snapshot. If these options are selected, the report will be run from older data in order to increase performance. Disable these to get the latest data.

Comment: That is the first thing I've checked and they are all turned off.

Comment: Well that would've been too easy!